# Sending Keyboard event to Off Screen Application using Java

Tags: java, events, keyboard

Hi want to send Event(keyboard press) on application thats not focused using Java .I searched for this in google but i found only if the application's screen is focused.

Comment: How many events for each user are we looking at here ?

Comment: What do you mean ? I want to send events when i want ?

Comment: when say events...you mean when a user clicks on a button etc...or you want capture what user has typed in a input box etc ?

Comment: i want to send Events to application (keyboard press) . Like Uopilot of you know

Comment: Basically OP is trying to achieve something similar to a "keylogger"...

Comment: I asked the same thing on the "Sun Forums" a few years ago and the answer I got was "Not Possible with pure java"

Comment: Keysender not Keylogger Like Robot.sendkey

Comment: You have to establish your own native event loop, attached to the OS's message queue and filter out the events you want. This an only be achieved through the use of JNI or JNA in Java...

Comment: isn't there a way by using Java Script and calling JS by Java using Script Engine?

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you tell me more about what you mean

Comment: You need to establish a connection to the OS's message queue, which is where all the OS level events are broadcasted from. You need to filter these events to get the key events and probably apply some kind of translation to determine what key was pressed.  This can only be achieved through the use of some native code using either JNI or JNA based solutions. I've used TeamDev's WinPack and JNI based solutions in the past to achieve this and I believe the JNA has some examples. Try doing a search got JNA...

Comment: i want to send bro not to determinate

Comment: @Patrick_Pichler
read the title: Off Screen

Answer (score 0):

You can send key events by using the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```